# How to set Div to appear behind another div on scroll?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a navigation bar under a header div tag 
and a slideshow div afterwards ... as the code shows

```
<div class="header">
   <div id="navbar">
       content    
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
        slideshow content    
    </div>
</div>
```

the header and navbar have a fixed position to stay on top of the page when scrolling , the problem is when I scroll my "slideshow" appears on top of the navbar but the rest of the page content does not, how can I fix this ?

**CSS styles**

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0 ;
}
```

Different CSS sheet for header and navbar

```
.header {
    background: #2f3036;
    height: 51px;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#ime-nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background:#FF9900;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

apparently I just needed to add a z-index to the header, completely overlooked it

```
.header {
    background: #2f3036;
    height: 51px;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```